# perfect circle in css with border-radius doesn't work

Tags: html, css

the circle tend be oval, what I want is perfect circle. border-radius 100% isn't work I wonder why..

http://jsfiddle.net/8gD2m/1/

```
.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: lighter !important;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: #d73d33;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to have the same `padding` on all sides for this to work. Might want to also try reducing your `line-height`. This will probably also only work for single-digit numbers. Extra digits will increase the necessary width, but the height will remain the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a JSfiddle with some changes:

[JSFiddle for round badge](http://jsfiddle.net/az35y/4/)

The main changes are:

```
padding: 0px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
```

Having a line-height equal to the container height will center the text vertically. This only works if the text fits on a single line.

**Edit:** (copied code from JSFiddle)

```css
.badge {
    display: inline-block;
   
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;    
    line-height: 50px;
    
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: lighter !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: #d73d33;
    border-radius:50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<span class="badge badge-success">8</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

if it's not perfect circle check display: inline-block and border-radius: 50%:

```
 .cirlce {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-weight:600;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: lighter !important;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: #d73d33;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main trick for making it a perfect circle is distributing the **padding** of the element(container) **evenly**  => then setting `border-radius: 50%` or  `border-radius: 100%`.
So you can get rid of the height and width declaration and use **absolute positioning** and **padding** to control the height and width

or same height and width and uniform padding value

```
 .element-class {
    Position: absolute;
    padding: 10em or 10% or with any unit;
    border-radius: 50% or 100%;
  }

OR

.element-class {
 height: 10em;
 width: 10em;
 padding: 10em;   **
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When I added a 100% border-radius, my picture turned into an oval. That is because my picture is wider than it is tall. Imagine smoothing the edges of a rectangle. If you want your image to be circular, you have to make sure the height and width dimensions are the same. You could try setting them by doing the following:

css height: 200px; width: 200px; (so the point is having equal height and with in your  CSS)

This will make sure that your image is circular, however, it may cause your image to stretch and become distorted because your originally image is NOT a perfect square I presume.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vw unit for width and height.
Like the sample below:

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20vw;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>resize device</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent a circle from becoming an oval, it may be necessary to include min-height and min-width additionally.

```
.circle {
      min-height: 50px;
      min-width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).